# How to combine multiple commits on same file?

Tags: git, gerrit

I got multiple commits on file xyz uploaded by other developer and each commit has different changes and there is no merge conflict exist.

I want to run a test on file xyz before submit to make sure changes has no impact on production. I don't want to test my file one by one with each commit.

Is there any way to combine all commits so that I can test file which contains all added changes?

Comment: `git rebase -i`?

Comment: Check out the last commit that modified the file? This will check out a file containing all the changes, unless some of them were later removed but you would have that problem whatever solution you pick.

Comment: thanks that's right.